# String manipulation required before using it as an object key

Tags: typescript

I have an object:

```
const myObject = {
    aaa: 'a value',
    bbb: 'b value',
    ccc: 'c value',
}
```

At runtime, I may receive strings like `aaa 1`, `aaa 2` and `bbb 3` etc, which will go through certain string manipulation before being used as a key into the object. In code terms:

```
const input = 'aaa 1'
const correctKey = inuput.substring(0, input.indexOf(' ')) // so now correctKey is 'aaa'
console.log(myObject[correctKey]) // my goal is to have 'a value' returned
```

Now the compiler error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ aaa: string; bbb: string; ccc: string; }'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ aaa: string; bbb: string; ccc: string;  }'

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `input` is assigned at runtime, you can only hint the compiler that `correctKey` is one of the keys of `myObject`:

```
const correctKey = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(' ')) as keyof typeof myObject;
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDCTAIYUBcMA5GTAG5kA2ArhjQDTGkp-U0UjFuy48SwSQODC2HbgF9ChUJFgBLMAAdWuWhXoBGGivDQYoAE6WsUANIYEMPJp1QAdBFYpolzQHMACgAGThhXXXdNABMMAA8kADNAmloASjTyCBgAa0cQRJgoBC0MAvhkdFsAblNIEGYMd2YQIMRUTGwAbSsbbAcEAF002qA)