# Typescript type of variable that comes from an object map?

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
const myMap = {
  a: {}, //assume both these objects have something in them
  b: {}
};

const option = myMap[request.body.option];
```

Now, request has type `any`. So the `const option`... line throws this:

*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{ a: {...etc}; b: {...etc}; }'.*

Is there any way to fix this? I'm already making sure `option` param is always passed.

Comment: Presumably `request.body.option` is expected to be either `"a"` or `b"`, so you'll need to provide that type information somewhere. You could just assert it in what you've shown, but there's likely a better option that a [mre] would make clear - probably `request` _shouldn't_ be `any`.

Comment: `request.body.option as keyof typeof myMap` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267316/string-manipulation-required-before-using-it-as-an-object-key/73267438#73267438

Comment: @skink is the type assertion I _don't_ think is a good idea. Give the type system the information to help you, don't just steamroll over it, or you might as well just write JS. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73204374/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe on a second thought, you are right, maybe there's indeed an option to set the `request` type in the framework OP is using.

Comment: @skink I'm using next, your solution works but I hear it's not the best option?

Comment: Then @jonrsharpe is right and e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69895731) can explain a much better way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to avoid this problem. The easy but unsafe solution is, to just tell Typescript that the `request.body.options` has a specific type for example:

```
interface MyInterface {
 a: {}, //assume both these objects have something in them
 b: {}
}


const option = myMap[<MyInterface>request.body.option];
```

This way the typescript compiler trusts you, that `request.body.options` will fulfill the provided interface. But since the request comes from the end user and could be modified and contain anything, the content should be checked to fulfill the expected interface or weird bugs can occur or you could even introduce security vulnerabilities.

You could do the validation through typeguards, which is a typescript native feature. An typeguard is an function which checks if something has an type:

```
function isMyInterface(x: unknown): x is MyInterface {
   if(typeof x !== 'obejct') return false;
   ...
}
```

This may be tedious and you could do also some errors. Therefore libraries like [`class-validator`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-decorators) can do the work for you:

```
import {
  validateOrReject,
  ValidateNested
} from 'class-validator';

class MyClass {
  @ValidateNested()
  a: MyAClass;
}

class MyAClass {
  @Contains('hello')
  text: string;

  @IsInt()
  @Min(0)
  @Max(10)
  rating: number;

  @IsEmail()
  email: string;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `keyof MyInterface`?